# Populating Django Templates from retrieved records

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I'm familar with using templates to collect the data, but on displaying is there a smart way that Django will display the fields and populate them with the right values. I can do it manually of course, but the model knows the field type. I didn't see any documentation on this. For example I collect data from the template with:

```
   <strong>Company Name</strong>
   <font color="red">{{ form.companyname.errors }}</font>
   {{ form.companyname }}
```

where form is my company model containing all the fields. How would I go about ensuring that I could use this type of methodology such that Django would render the text fields and populate with the current values. For example is there a way to send in values in the following way:

```
    myid = int(self.request.get('id'))
    myrecord = Company.get_by_id(myid)
    category_list = CompanyCategory.all()
    path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'editcompany.html')
    self.response.out.write(template.render(path, {'form': myrecord, 'category_list': category_list}))
```

Can I do the same this with records and will the template populate with values sent in? Thanks

Comment: or something like {% for field in form %}
                {{ field }}
            {% endfor %}

Comment: @JureC. I tried this, but the form doesn't seem to render at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you may be confused about the difference and proper usage of `Form` vs `ModelForm`

Regardless of which type of form you use, the templating side of forms stays the same:
Note: all of the values in your form (as long as its bound to POST or has an instance) will be prepopulated at render.

```
<form class="well" action="{% url member-profile %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset>
        {{ form.non_field_errors }}

        {{ form.display_name.label_tag }}
        <span class="help-block">{{ form.display_name.help_text }}</span>
        {{ form.display_name }}
        <span class="error">{{ form.display_name.errors }}</span>

        {{ form.biography.label_tag }}
        <span class="help-block">{{ form.biography.help_text }}</span>
        {{ form.biography }}
        <span class="error">{{ form.biography.errors }}</span>

        <input type="submit" class="button primary" value="Save" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

if you want to be populating a form from a record (or submit a form as a record) its probably best to use `ModelForm`

EX a profile form that doesn't display the User FK dropdown:

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """Profile form"""      
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        exclude = ('user',)
```

The View:

```
def profile(request):
    """Manage Account"""
    if request.user.is_anonymous() :
        # user isn't logged in
        messages.info(request, _(u'You are not logged in!'))
        return redirect('member-login')

    # get the currently logged in user's profile
    profile = request.user.profile

    # check to see if this request is a post
    if request.method == "POST":
        # Bind the post to the form w/ profile as initial
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance=profile)
        if form.is_valid() :
            # if the form is valid
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, _(u'Success! You have updated your profile.'))
        else :
            # if the form is invalid
            messages.error(request, _(u'Error! Correct all errors in the form below and resubmit.'))
    else:
        # set the initial form values to the current user's profile's values
        form = ProfileForm(instance=profile)

    return render(
        request, 
        'membership/manage/profile.html', 
        {
            'form': form, 
        }
    )
```

notice that the outer `else` initializes the form with an instance: `form = ProfileForm(instance=profile)` and that the form submit initializes the form with post, BUT still binds to instance `form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance=profile)`

Comment: Thanks, I have it now. Simple really...sometimes I do long a little bit better documentation on Django that resonates with me.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking at forms, it would seem like a good idea to start with Django's [forms framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/), specifically [forms for models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/modelforms/).